# unable to create parquet converter for data type "timestamp" whose parquet type is optional binary (string)

Tags: sql, databricks, parquet

I'm currently getting an error where when trying to do a copy into a delta table with a parquet file, one of the timestamp columns is throwing a unable to create parquet converter for data type "timestamp" whose parquet type is optional binary (string) error. Using databricks, I read the parquet file into a dataframe and found that the timestamp columns contain two values, null and yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss*SSSZZZZ format value.

I tried to use coalesce function to replace the null values and trying to create a table with
 timestamp NULL, but this throws a syntax error. I'm using spark.sql in order to do a copy into.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.